# Incorrect credentials for repository at ssh

Tags: netbeans, ssh, repository, openshift

I'm totally confused with openshift+netbeans. [This is my openshift app and repository address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUrTR.jpg)

When I try to "Clone repository" in order to develop locally I meet "Incorrect credentials for repository at ssh..." I also noticed that it is not possible to put the URL provided by openshift to "Repository URL" field in Netbeans "Clone repository" tool. [Clone repository screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXxLi.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

> I meet "Incorrect credentials for repository at ssh..."

Yes, as expected, because you use (in Netbeans) strange and unknown username.

Format of ssh-URL is well-known and predefined. For SSH-served Git-repos it's

```
ssh://[USERNAME@]HOSTNAME:[PORT]/PATH/TO/REPO.git
```

optional parameters are `[]`-ed

If Netbeans doesn't accept username in URL, you **must** use same name, as suggested in app's configuration (long HEX-string), for SSH, not username `...@yandex.ru` (this is login for OpenShift, not for SSH).

And you can start from getting functional SSH-connection (SSH-client with interactive authentication) before configuring VCS settings in Netbeans

Answer (score 1):

OK, it works! So the solution is:

1. Repository URL like: ssh://myapp-mydomen.rhcloud.com/~/git/caswp.git/
2. User name is like: 123e31f89f5cf29a111110e (you can find it on OPENSHIFT ONLINE on app page)
3. I used "private key". The file name is - **id_rsa** Normally you can find it in folder - C:\Users\UserName.ssh\

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I can tell that its just an user information miss match issue. I have two repository at bitbucket.org. I was trying to clone with wrong username/password from netbeans where Netbeans checks authentication. 
Suddenly i notice that and correct the username/password and BANG it works... no error!!!.